# Why un-defining a macro takes effect before #undef is reached?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f(void);

#define N 100

int main(void)
{
    f();
#ifdef N
#undef N
#endif

    return 0;
}

void f(void){
#if defined(N)
  printf("N is %d\n",N);
#else
  printf("N is undefined\n");
#endif // defined
}
```

Sorry same question like before but little different. Here same code it writes `N` is undefined

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f(void);

#define N 100

int main(void)
{
#if defined(N)
  printf("N is %d\n",N);
#else
  printf("N is undefined\n");
#endif // defined
/**f();
#ifdef N
#undef N
#endif**/

return 0;
}

/**void f(void){
}**/
```

But if I write the definitions from the `f` function in main instead it prints the output `N` is 100. Why does this print occur and why the difference?

Comment: The preprocessor is strictly sequential, it goes through the source from top to bottom, and don't know anything about functions or scopes or the flow of the program.

Comment: .. As hinted in the previous post - Perhaps this might help http://comsci.liu.edu/~murali/c/PreprocessCompileLink.htm

Comment: Thanks for the link to Ed Heal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to separate in your mind two timelines:

- **The compiling timeline** - i.e. things that happen as your program is being compiled, and
- **The running timeline** - i.e. the things that happen as your program runs

These two timelines are independent of each other. The compiling timeline roughly corresponds to the textual order of your program, with some corrections for `#include` processing and macro expansions. The running timeline is decided by your program's control structures, function invocations, and so on.

Since these two timelines are independent, a point X in code that is reached *before* point Y during the compile timeline may very well be reached *after* point Y during the running timeline. Moreover, it may be reached multiple times - both before and after another point Y.

Now let's go back to your question. **`#define`s and macros are expanded at compile time**, so *before* and *after* refer exclusively to the compile timeline. When you place `#undef` in `main`, above your function `f`, the un-definition happens *before* the use of `N`, leading to the compile-time error. The running timeline, according to which the call of `f` happens *before* the un-definition has no relevance, because `#define`s are an exclusively compile-time construct.

Comment: Thanks i have things to think about!